# Scientific poster printing prices

Tags: data-request, research

I am looking for a dataset containing prices of scientific poster printing with as many following fields as possible:

- Location
- Poster sizes
- Prices
- Poster options (e.g., glossy)

---

I am mostly interested in the following locations:

- California, United States
- Massachusetts, United States
- Paris, France
- Seoul, South Korea